# Fieldsets for site builders

Tags: entities, 8

In Drupal 7, it's possible to group fields for a content type with fieldsets, vertical tabs and so on.

Where are this options in Drupal 8? I didn't find something in the *Manage fields* or *Manage form display* tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That functionality is provided by the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module.

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.

There is a Drupal 8 version available.